# change color of WinJS.UI.SearchBox?

Tags: javascript, winjs, windows-8.1

How to change the color of `WinJS.UI.SearchBox` ? icon and text color.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is any Color option for `WinJS.UI.SearchBox`.

Input color :

```
.win-searchbox-suggestion-selected,
.win-searchbox-suggestion-selected:hover,
.win-searchbox-suggestion-selected:focus,
.win-searchbox-button-input-focus,
.win-searchbox-button-input-focus:hover
 {
     background-color : #e2001a; //your color
     color : #000; 
 }

.win-searchbox-flyout-highlighttext
{
   color : #c0009a;
   background: transparent;
}
```

Selected text color :

```
::selection {
 background-color:  #e2001a;
 color : #000;
}
```